# Netdata logs everything to mysql logs

Tags: mysql, centos7, mariadb, netdata

Since I enabled mariadb logs for all queries on my server, using Netdata shows me each second these queries:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'
11 Query     SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
11 Query     commit
```

I have to say it's not helping me to invest what's going on on the server because it's polluting my logs.

Is there a way to avoid logging this kind of query each sec?

Comment: Please explain why have you enabled logging and what's wrong with your server in the first place...

Comment: @Anubioz well this is not relevant to tell why I enabled mysql logging, the issue is not here

Answer (score 1):

While it's probably [wiser to specify the exact problem with your database instead of trying to clean up the log](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/338172) (I'd suggset using grep or sed for that). But here's an over-engineered solution, which will solve your logging problem once and for all.

We'll be redirecting mysql logs to a fifo pipe, which will be read & filtered by syslog-ng.

To do that go to the folder, where general-log-file is stored, delete/rename the original log & create a fifo pipe on its place with the command:

```
mkfifo mysql-general.log
```

check your my.cnf which should point to that file:

```
[mysqld]
general-log-file = /path/to/your/log/mysql-general.log
```

Then, configure your `/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf` ([centos 7 would actually require installing it first](https://www.syslog-ng.com/community/b/blog/posts/installing-latest-syslog-ng-on-rhel-and-other-rpm-distributions)) to read the FIFO pipe and filter it as needed while writing result into the final file..

Here's an example configuration, that suits your needs:

```
source s_mysql_general_log { pipe("/path/to/your/log/mysql-general.log" program_override("mysql-general-log")); };
filter f_mysql_general_log { not match("^SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'") and not match("^11 Query     SHOW GLOBAL STATUS") and not match("^11 Query     commit"); };
destination d_mysql_general_log { file("/var/log/mysql-general.log"); }
log { source(s_mysql_general_log); filter(f_mysql_general_log); destination(d_mysql_general_log); flags(final);   };
```

As a result, you'll get `/var/log/mysql-general.log` file without queries you dislike...
I'll try to post a systemd-only version of this solution a bit later

Comment: Thanks I gonna try this tomorrow